# To call a zoo blog latest post item in article

Tags: joomla2.5, blogs

How to clall a zoo blog latest post in joomla article. I am using joomla2.5.9 version and the zoo version is com_zoo_3.0.10. I want the code.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use zoo object with joomla article directly, but you can create a new module that load zoo lastet posts and assign it to a position in the article page.